# How to do find queries on associated fields in sails

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

Is it possible to query on associated fields properties in sails. For example, let's consider these two model:

**Product**:

```
attributes: {
    name:{
        type:'string'
    },
    code:{
        type:'string',
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    inventory:{
        collection:'inventory',
        via:'product'
    }
}
```

**Inventory**

```
attributes: {
    product:{
        model:'product',
        required:true
    },
    quantity:{
        type:'float'
    }
}
```

Now is there any way to get `Inventory` records that have `Products` of certain `codes`. One way is to get `products` of those specific `codes` and then get `Inventory` records having those `products`. But is it possible to do a single `find` query to get desired result? I have tried following, but this does not filter `products` on `code`.

```
Inventory
    .find()
    .populate('product',{where:{code:{'contains':'something'}}})
    .exec(function (err, inventories) {
        //do something
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact with your request you take all Inventory and populate only product with `code:{'contains':'something'}` other inventory will have empty products.

You can make your association two way and do this :

```
Product
    .find().where({code:{'contains':'something'}})
    .populate('inventory')
    .exec(function (err, products) {
        //do something
        //Build an array of inventory with async on all products
    })
```

As I know there is no other way to do this actually :/

Comment: I have thought of this. But if i want to use `skip` and `limit` on the result then the code becomes kind of messy. Accumulate all the results to an array and then skip some records and take next records and then return.

Comment: I understand but I don't have any other solution except doing manually the sql request with .query if I remember correctly

Comment: It is a feature that is actively being worked on for the the next release of waterline.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can`t. Best option you have - it is NOT use sails ever!